# PHP, MySQL How to Sum data in two different date range

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Im having trouble doing this

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|   Name     | year       | Value      |
+------------+------------+------------+
| Name1      | 2015       |        100 |
| Name1      | 2014       |        150 |
| Name1      | 2013       |        200 |
| Name2      | 2015       |        130 |
| Name2      | 2014       |        160 |
| Name2      | 2013       |        220 |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

The Value from (2015 to 2013) minus the value from (2014 to 2013)
Grouped by Name

which will OUTPUT

```
+------------+------------+
|   Name     | Value      |
+------------+------------+
| Name1      | 100        |
| Name2      | 130        |
+------------+------------+
```

Or is there anyway i can use SUM with WHERE something like

```
(SUM(Name1 WHERE year <= "2014") - SUM(Name1 WHERE year <= "2015") ) AS Value
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: "The Value from (2015 to 2013) minus the value from (2014 to 2013)" that means you want sum of the values in 2015 only right? So you will retrieve directly from table then why are using complex query ?

Comment: After Manually computing it with the actual data (with Credit and Debit)
your solution works i Didnt notice that LOL. .

Thnx Soo much Vignesh Bala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something Like this

```
 SELECT (SUM(IF(year <= 2015 AND year >= 2013,value,0) )
         - SUM(IF(year <= 2014 and year >= 2013,value,0) )) AS total_sum
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY Name
```

This will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 SELECT (SUM(IF(`year` <= 2015 and `year` >= 2013,value,0) ) ) as total_sum_2015 FROM `table`
```

do same for 2014
like this

```
SELECT (
    SUM( IF( `year` <=2014
    AND `year` >=2013, value, 0 ) )
    ) AS total_sum_2014
    FROM `table`
```